# hacer búsqueda en subcadena en java

Tags: java, string, netbeans, scanner, substring

hola buendia alguien me ayuda con este ejercicio no fue capas ni de empezarlo es en java

Carlos tiene una gran colección de música, y es muy particular
con las canciones que escucha. Cada canción tiene un nombre, que
es una cadena de caracteres. Su reproductor de música tiene una
función de búsqueda que permite a Carlos escribir una subcadena
en búsqueda, y a continuación, enumera todas las canciones cuyos
nombres contengan la subcadena. Si no es exactamente una
canción que coincide con la búsqueda.
Carlos odia usar el ratón, y que no le gusta escribir mucho, así que
insiste en escribir siempre la subcadena más breve posible que
coincide exactamente con la canción que quiere escuchar en este
momento. Crear un algoritmo que supla las necesidades de Carlos.

Comment: Aquí no se realizan tareas académicas a menos que: exista intentos demostrables de haber investigado para alguna solución, dicho en otras palabras, edita la pregunta e incluye lo que hayas intentado + lo que hayas investigado. Caso contrario, que no te sorprenda si la pregunta queda cerrada y/o con votos negativos. Finalmente te recuerdo visitar https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla, por otro lado, aquí unas recomendaciones de cómo preguntar: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Ánimo que sí puedes.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.